# Apply CodeMirror to pre-existing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, contenteditable, codemirror

I have a div called content_editable. I am making a code editing application. So there are certain css dimensions it needs to follow. But I want to be able to add the code mirror syntax highlighting script to it. But when I do it the way the documentation says to do it, nothing happens. At all. My div to be edited is called `#editable_content`. How do I add the CodeMirror capabilities to it?

#### EDIT

link to the site documentation [CodeMirror Documentation](http://codemirror.net/manual.html)
Also, a link to a JSFiddle or a JSBin would be greatly appreciated for example reasons

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this (untested) should do the trick

```
var ce = document.getElementById("content_editable");
// Probably needs more kludges to be portable... you get the idea
var text = ce.textContent || ce.innerText;
var editor = CodeMirror(function(node){ce.parentNode.replaceChild(node, ce);}, {
  value: text
  /* , your options */
});
```